# Запятые в обращениях?

Tags: пунктуация

1. А вы, знаете что-нибудь об этом человеке ? (правильно?)
2. Вы знаете что-нибудь об этом человеке ?
3. А вы, не знали, что Вася уже давно приехал ? (можно поставить запятую после "вы" для усиления интонации, а можно не ставить?)
4. А вы знаете, в соседней деревне жених украл члена партии.

или

```
   А вы знаете? В соседней деревне жених украл члена партии.
```

Comment: Опять у Вас домашнее задание?

Answer (score 1):

В ваших примерах нет обращений.
Видите ли, если вы обращаетесь к кому-нибудь, то это не значит, что непременно используете обращение.

> > А вы, знаете что-нибудь об этом человеке?

Вы разделили запятой подлежащее и сказуемое, это грубейшая ошибка. Представляете: *Мама, мыла раму*.